# How the dot product of two vectors can be zero?

Tags: vectors

I am given,

**$\vec s$**$=2\hat i+\hat j-3\hat k$

and

**$\vec r$**$=4\hat i+\hat j+3\hat k$

Now I am asked to calculate the dot product **$\vec s\cdot\vec r$** 
But I am getting $0$ as result.

Is this possible? And if possible, then how can the dot product simply become zero?

Comment: "*When I add the component parts*"  Why are you adding the component parts?  $\langle 2,1,-3\rangle$ is not the zero vector $\langle 0,0,0\rangle$.

Comment: "*Is this possible (to do a dot product with a zero vector)?  How can I calculate it?*" 
 Regardless of what the entries are, you have $\langle a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\rangle \cdot \langle b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\rangle = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \dots + a_nb_n$.  Further, if a vector is *actually* a zero vector (*i.e. every entry is zero*) you should see quickly that any dot product involving it will equal zero.  In your case, you are asked to calculate $\langle 2,1,-3\rangle \cdot \langle 4,1,3\rangle$.

Comment: Dot product zero iff vectors orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec s.\vec r=(2\hat i+\hat j-3\hat k)\cdot(4\hat i+\hat j+3\hat k)=8+1-9=0$$
that means $\vec s$ and $\vec r$ are perpendicular to each other.the intuition behind this dot product is what amount of $\vec s$ is working along with $\vec r$?If we would get some positive value,then that would mean that there is some component of s along r as it brings us in a conclusion that s would be inclined to r.But we have a zero here,that means no component of s is working along r.it is only possible when vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you, that explains the above comments and helps a lot!